# Correct way of declaring javascript array?

Tags: javascript

I have seen the second way of declaring an array and I want to know what kind of javascript is that because when I try to use that I have syntax errors all over the place. Is the second code used in node.js? Or some other framework of that sort?

```
var array = [1, 2, 3];
```

**or**

```
int[] array = new int[]{1, 2, 3};
```

Or even, is the second way javascript?

Comment: You've probably seen that in some language which may or may not compile to Javascript (e.g. TypeScript), but *is not* Javascript.

Comment: The second sample looks to be C#-ish, so I even though I haven't used it, I wouldn't be surprised to know that is the syntax to write it in TypeScript (also by Microsoft). Anyway, the syntax is not Javascript.

Comment: The first is JavaScript, the second is Java. Those two, despite similar names, are totally unrelated.

Comment: @CRABOLO, that question has nothing to do with mine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Or even, is the second way javascript?

No, it is not. Your first version is the correct way to *create* an array. (You don't *declare* arrays in JavaScript, because JavaScript is a loosely-typed language.)

The two ways to create an array (other than as a by-product of calling a function like `slice` or `map`) are:

1. An array literal, which is what you've used in your first example:

   ```
   var a = [];                 // Initially blank
   var b = [1, 2, 3];          // Has three entries to start with
   ```
2. The `Array` constructor, but it's tricky and verbose, it's rare that you want to use it:

   ```
   var a = new Array();        // Initially blank
   var b = new Array(1, 2, 3); // Has three entries to start with
   ```

   The reason I say it's "tricky" is that if you give it just one argument, *and* that argument is a number, you're pre-setting the length, not giving it an entry. So:

   ```
   var c = new Array(7);       // Empty array with length of 7!
   ```

   This discrepancy between `new Array(7)` and `new Array(7, 7)` sometimes trips people up.

For completeness I should mention that JavaScript now (as of ECMAScript 2015) has other kinds of arrays as well, called *typed arrays*, such as `Int32Array`; many JavaScript engines supported them well before the specification as a whole was complete. You create those via the `new` operator, e.g. `var a = new Int32Array(7)`. The constructors for them don't have the tricky ambiguity of `new Array`, fortunately (they do have various different potential arguments, but not in the same way).

---

Side note: Your second example, `int[] array = new int[]{1, 2, 3};`, is valid syntax for both Java and C#, possibly some other languages as well.

Answer (score 1):

Its regular Java, and not JavaScript

Comment: You say it's Java, someone else says it's C# :)

Comment: @Ionut: It's both. This is a place where C#'s syntax exactly matches Java's.

Comment: Oh, okay, now I get it. Thanks.

Comment: @Ionut well guess what - its both! But since you are stumbling upon it in javascript related things, id guess you mistankenly find Java

Answer (score 1):

The second way is a C# way to declare an array of integers

Comment: You say it's C#, someone else says it's Java :)

Comment: Here you go some documentations:

Java -> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

C# -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx